# Login seems to be overflown from div

Tags: css, html

This is the header section which contains logo on the left side and login link on the right within the same div. I've been trying to get login text to not been overflown from the `#header_section`.

What's wrong with my code? By the way, I just start learning CSS.

```
div#container
{
    background: url(../images/bg_inner.png) repeat;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width:  950px; 
    text-align: left;
}

div#header_section
{
    width: 930px;
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
}

#logo
{
    background: url(../images/logo.png) left no-repeat;
    margin: 5px;
    border: none;
    height: 55px;
    width: 200px;
}

.login
{
    font-size: 22px;
    color:#4A4A4A;
    width: 60px;
    float: right;
}
```

---

```
<div id="header_section">
    <a href="index.php" id="logo"></a>
    <a href="login.php" class="login">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get a picture or a link to the site(if it's not local?).

Comment: Please try a fiddle if you can http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Wild-guess: change

```
div#header_section
{
    overflow: hidden;
    ...rest of stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a [clearing div](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) within your header section if the text is overflowing when it shouldn't. I'm only guessing this as you float you're login element (I'm assuming it's a div) to the right. It's difficult to tell without a detailed screenshot.

```
div#headerSection {
   ...
   overflow: auto;
   width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float an element you want to put it before the element that isn't floated. And as others have mentioned, you probably want a "clearing div" afterward, even if it works, just for good measure.

Basically, try this:

```
<div id="header_section">
    <a href="login.php" class="login">Login</a>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo"></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Then define the following for the "clearing div":

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```